# Access vs execute thread's method

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Does this line:

```
ClientThread.ClientSocket.getInputStream().read()
```

takes ClientThread's method and executes it on MainUI thread, or does it tell ClientThread to execute it?

It results in MainThreadNetworking Exception so I believe it's the first option, sadly. If so, how can I execute that method in the ClientThread instead?

Comment: The method is executed by the current thread.

Comment: 'It results in MainThreadNetworking Exception ': no it didn't. You got `NetworkingOnMainThreadException`. Be accurate.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to tell another thread to execute something. So, no, the above simply runs it in *your* thread. Note, there's the concept 'Thread -a thing that runs on an OS core' and 'java.lang.Thread - an object that represents that concept'. They are not quite identical. I'll use `j.l.Thread` to indicate the Thread object and just thread for the OS concept. `j.l.Thread` is **just an object**, it's not particularly magical. Just interacting with a `j.l.Thread` instance is just.. interacting with an object. It doesn't convey magical 'anything you do with this object somehow runs in a separate thread' powers.

There are only only 2 ways to tell another thread (OS-level or j.l.Thread) to execute something, i.e., only 2 ways to use `j.l.Thread` to actually run stuff in separate threads:

- When creating a `j.l.Thread`, you pass along the 'run()' code (either passing a Runnable, or extending Thread and supplying a `run()` method). When some thread runs the code `thatThreadObject.start()` (note: not run!) - then that starts an actual thread, and that newly created thread will, after initializing, begin by executing the code in that run() method of the `j.l.Thread` object.
- By programming it. In other words, perhaps some thread looks like this:

```
private class Runner extends Thread {
  private final ArrayBlockingQueue <Runnable> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1000);

  public void offer(Runnable r) {
    queue.add(r);
  }

  @Override public void run() {
    while (true) {
      Runnable r = queue.take();
      r.run();
    }
  }
}
```

Then, imagine some code is running in a thread (not the thread represented by the `j.l.Thread` instance made from the above code), and calls `thatThreadObj.offer(() -> System.out.println("Hello!");`...

then eventually the thread represented by that `j.l.Thread` will run it. Because you programmed it to do this.

If you want something like that, note that the `java.util.concurrent` package has implementations of this concept (`ExecutorPool` and friends). Don't write it yourself.